# Is it possible to set the z-rotation of a matrix without the use of quaternions?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to rotate my 3D camera with the mouse.

Since I can't make a lookAt function that does not gimbal lock without the use of quaternions I instead rotate the right & up axis respectively.

However, this makes the matrix rotate along it's forward axis as well which is a behaviour I don't want.

To prevent this I tried making a function that sets the y value of the right axis to 0, but my attempts only leads to the matrix getting more obscure when rotated further.

So my question is if it's possible to do this at all?
I'm using a left-hand matrix where x is right, y is up & z is forward.

This is an example in C++, so you can see what I'm going for:

```
void RemoveZRotation(Matrix44& matrix)
{
    Vector3 right = matrix.GetRight();
    right.y = 0;
    right.Normalize();

    Vector3 up = right.Cross(matrix.GetForward());
    up.Normalize();

    matrix[0] = right.x;
    matrix[1] = right.y;
    matrix[2] = right.z;

    matrix[4] = up.x;
    matrix[5] = up.y;
    matrix[6] = up.z;
}
```

Comment: A rotation matrix contains the directions of the local _x_, _y_ and _z_ vectors as columns. So instead of modifying a 3D rotation, generate a new one with two rotations only

Comment: As you said a matrix contains directions, but as far as I know the rotation values themselves have to be calculated. So I could create a matrix with 2 set directions, but not rotations.                                                                                              Maybe I'm missing something here, but I do not know how I would go about doing that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing here, but you may also be interested in [How to avoid gimbal lock](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51410/44707)

Comment: @EricNilsson yes, if the local (eye) coordinate has direction vectors **x**, **y** and **z** then the rotation matrix is `R = [x y z]`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you there. I can make rotation matrixes that are rotated in one axis, but not in multiple at once. It's when I combine 2 seperate matrixes that causes the problem. If there is a good way to create a matrix with 2 rotations at once I would gladly like to know.